# Posix threads:Signal a thread that is running in while loop

Tags: multithreading, unix, pthreads, signals, posix

I have a thread that is a very simple: it sends keep-alive packets to a server, then sleeps. I would like my main thread to signal the thread to quit, but whenever I call pthread_kill() it seems to crash my process.

I tried to call sigpending() followed by sigismember() at the beginning of my while loop, but I think it is crashing because it doesn't know of any handle to take care of the signal (I was using sigaddset() before the while loop), as follow:

```
void* foo(void* arg)
{
    sigset_t set, isSignal;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    if (sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1) == -1) { /* ... */ }

    while (1) {
        if (sigpending(&isSignal) != 0) { /* .. */ }
        else if (sigismember(&isSignal, SIGUSR1)) {
            break;
        }

        sendKeepAlive();
        sleep(SECONDS);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

It seems pthread_kill(pth, SIGUSR1); makes the program dies. What is the right way to send the signal please? Should I use pthread_sigmask() instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A signal is pending when it is delivered by the OS but a process or thread has *blocked* it.  If you haven't blocked SIGUSR1 then it is going to be delivered and the default disposition of SIGUSR1 is to terminate the process.  Your `sigpending` is doing nothing in this scenario; it is effectively bypassed.  Either block SIGUSR1 first with `pthread_sigmask` or (optionally) handle it.

Over all this is a dubious design.  With the blocked/sigpending code, depending on how long SECONDS is set to you can still wait a long time before your thread loops around to discover it is time to shutdown.  If you really want to use signals for this I would suggest establishing a signal handler that sets a switch.  When SIGUSR1 gets delivered the handler will be invoked, it sets the switch, `sleep` will be interrupted by the signal, you check for EINTR and immediately loop around to check the switch and then`pthread_exit`.

**Option 1** (compiled on linux)

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

void* foo(void* arg)
{
    sigset_t set, isSignal, allSigs;

    sigfillset(&allSigs);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &allSigs, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("sigprocmask: %m\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sigemptyset(&set);

    if (sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1) == -1)
    {
        printf("sigaddset: %m\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        if (sigpending(&isSignal) != 0)
        {
            printf("sigpending: %m\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            if (sigismember(&isSignal, SIGUSR1))
            {
                printf("signal pending for thread, exiting\n");
                break;
            }

        printf("Doing groovy thread stuff...\n");

        sleep(2);
    }

    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int rc;

    rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, foo, NULL);

    if (rc)
    {
        printf("pthread_create: %m\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sleep(10);

    pthread_kill(tid, SIGUSR1);

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

}
```

**Option 2** (compiled on linux)

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile int stop = 0;

void handler(int sig)
{
    stop = 1;
}

void* foo(void* arg)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler); //use sigaction, i'm too lazy here

    while (! stop)
    {
        printf("Doing groovy thread stuff...\n");

        if (sleep(4) > 0)
            if (errno == EINTR)
            {
                printf("sleep interrupted, exiting thread...\n");
                continue;
            }
    }

    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int rc;

    rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, foo, NULL);

    if (rc)
    {
        printf("pthread_create: %m\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sleep(10);

    pthread_kill(tid, SIGUSR1);

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

}
```

**Option 3** *Use some other mechanism if you can.  Advised.*

Comment: Thank you, option 2 works really well for me, and I agree, it's good that I interrupt the sleep and exit when EINTR. I really like this solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'd lose the signal stuff and just use a pthread conditional variable instead, for example pthread_cond_timedwait()):

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posix3/

IMHO...